# jQuery Event Bubble

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have a mousedown event attached in an anchor element which does many stuffs.

I also have a mousedown event attached to the document, and because of bubbling this event is called whenever the event attached to anchor is triggered. This is not what I want.

Can I bind a event with delay? 
I dont want to use stopPropagation.

```
$('a').mousedown ->
  ...
  openWindow()
  $(document).mousedown ->
     ...
     closeWindow()
```

**Edit**

I create a hack

```
$.fn.onBubble = (events, selector, data, handler) ->
    setTimeout => 
        this.on events, selector, data, handler 
    , 0
```

Work but like very ugly

Comment: You're not going to be able to prevent the bubbling *without* `event.stopPropagation()`, so far as I can imagine...

Comment: I want stop only for de current bubble when I declare its

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As one of the comments mentions, the only way to stop events from bubbling is with [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).  That said, if there are both conditions where you *do* want to prevent bubbling and others where you *do not*, you can put `event.stopPropagation()` into an if-statement:

```
$(...).mousedown(function(event) {
    if(/* some condition */) { event.stopPropagation(); }
});
```

Alternatively you can add a conditional to the event handler attached to the document.  For example:

```
$(document).mousedown(function(event) {
    if($(event.target).is("a")) {
        return; // if the element that originally trigged this event
                // (i.e. the target) is an anchor, then immediately return.
    }
    /** code that runs if event not from an anchor **/
});
```

This snippet uses [`$.fn.is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to determine if the event was triggered by an anchor.  If it is generated by an anchor, the code immediately returns, which in effect ignores the event bubble.

**EDIT in response to comment:**

If I understand correctly, you want to close the window, if the user clicks on anything that is *not* in the window. In that case try this:

```
function whenWindowOpens { // Called when the window is opened
    var windowElement; // Holds actual window element (not jQuery object)
    $(document).bind("mousedown", function(event) {
        if($.contains(windowElement, event.target)) {
            return; // Ignore mouse downs in window element
        }

        if($(event.target).is(windowElement)) {
            return; // Ignore mouse downs on window element
        }

        /** close window **/

        $(this).unbind(event); // detaches event handler from document
    });
}
```

This is basically a variation on the second solution suggested above.  The first two if-statements ensure the mouse down did not occur in (using [`$.contains`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)) or on (using [`$.fn.is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) again) the `windowElement`.  When both statements are false, we close the window and unbind the current event handler.  Note that `$.contains` only takes raw DOM elements -- *not* jQuery objects.  To get the raw DOM element from a jQuery object use [`$.fn.get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).

Comment: I dont want to use stopPropagation because it is an app. I only want to open a window and attach an event in document to close it. I can do that using a overlay layer but i dont want too

Comment: I think I better understand your problem.  I've edited my answer to add a possible solution.